# .find() with Discord Bots

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord

Let's say i have this:

```
let res = body.classes.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase()) || body.typedefs.find(t => t.name.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase())
```

How would I check if the output of res is from body.classes or body.typedefs?

Comment: What is your array data?

Answer (score 0):

The output will be from `body.classes` if `body.classes.find` instruction returns something. Else, it will be the result from `body.typedefs.find`.

```js
const body = {
  classes: [
    { name: 'name1' },
    { name: 'name2' },
    { name: 'name3' },
  ],
  typedefs: [
    { name: 'name1' },
    { name: 'name2' },
    { name: 'name3' },
    { name: 'name4' }
  ]
};

const arg1 = 'NAME1';
const res1 = body.classes.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === arg1.toLowerCase()) || body.typedefs.find(t => t.name.toLowerCase() === arg1.toLowerCase());
console.log(res1);

const arg2 = 'NAME4';
const res2 = body.classes.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === arg2.toLowerCase()) || body.typedefs.find(t => t.name.toLowerCase() === arg2.toLowerCase());
console.log(res2);
```

So if you want to check if the output is from `body.classes` or from `body.typedefs`, you just have to store the output of each `find` function in different variables and then check them. Something like

```
const findClasses = body.classes.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase());

const findTypedefs = body.typedefs.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === args[0].toLowerCase());

let res = findClasses || findTypedefs;

if (findClasses) {
  console.log('Ouput from body.classes.find:', findClasses);
}

if (findTypedefs) {
  console.log('Ouput from body.typedefs.find:', findTypedefs);
}
```